# Windows 10 h264 videos with QMediaPlayer

Tags: qt, video, windows-10, h.264

I'd like to play h264 videos with QMediaPlayer on Windows 10. It does not work. The video does not appear. It works on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. Do I need to install some additional program?

It works on Windows 7, 8.1 and Linux. I've tried playing the videos on different laptops with Windows 10.

edit:
I get an unresolved error code from doRender when playing the .MOV file:
[image]

Comment: This is a **programming question**, right? Given only what you've written, what do you think the **correct** answer looks like to this question? No-one is psychic enough to know what your playback **code** looks like, no-one knows the **profile** settings of your h.264 video... Did you try other media players like **VLC** or **Media Player HC** to confirm other people's code can play the files on Win10?

Comment: PS: I did not downvote but if this question amounts to _"what program can I download to play video files on my ccomputer?"_ then those down-votes & close votes are justified. It's off-topic for a programming Q&A site.

Comment: I've added a screenshot with an error code. It works on Windows 7 and 8.1 and Linux so I don't think it is related to a programming error. Yet it is about Qt and the multimedia framework so it is related to programming.

Comment: Seems there is a bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51692

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been reported as a bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51692
and a open feature request: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32783

"-wmf-backend" Use wmf as backend for QMultimedia. Otherwise MP4 videos won't be supported when DirectShow is used"

so you have to build Qt 5 manually or use another format. Maybe .wmf works.