# How to add video to Pyqt5 background?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Hello I'm trying to add `galaxy.mp4` file to my pqt5 window background with below source codes, when I try with this, any video showing and starting application closed and didnt give any error. How can I solve this ? Im using Windows10

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtMultimediaWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtCore, QtGui, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTransform
import sys    

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.setWindowTitle("Welcome Galaxy")
        self.Welcome()
        self.show()


    def Welcome(self):

        # create link to movie file
        movie_file = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('./galaxy.mp4')
        vid_media = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(movie_file)

        # create video widget
        self.videoWidget = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()
        self.videoWidget.setGeometry(0,0,1920,1080)

        # create media player object   (video widget goes in media player)
        self.mediaPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(None,
                                                     QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
        # playlist
        self.playlist = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlaylist()
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QtMultimedia.QMediaPlaylist.Loop)
        self.playlist.addMedia(vid_media)
        # add content to media player
        self.mediaPlayer.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.videoWidget)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use an absolute path, not a relative one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 h264 videos with QMediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180225/windows-10-h264-videos-with-qmediaplayer)